# iOS share extension display name

Tags: ios, uikit, share-extension

My app supports 2 different share extensions, and I distinguish between them using the CFBundleDisplayName in the Info.plist file for both extensions. This worked fine in iOS12, but in iOS13, it seems that it only shows the app's display name instead, which makes it confusing to have two share actions in the share sheet with the same name.

Is this new functionality in iOS13 that I'm unaware of? Is there a work-around to continue supporting 2 share extensions from the same app? I haven't found any documentation on this change in behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is very simple. You can change the Display name of any extension from Build Settings.

[image]

Comment: This worked in Ventura 13.4 with Xcode 15b1.

Answer (score 0):

We're having the same issue. I only found a thread at [Apple Developer](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122248) ... but that's not an answer, how to provide multiple extensions with different display names in iOS 13.

Comment: I filed a Radar, and the feedback I got was that "this was expected behavior". I take it to mean that multiple share extensions aren't supported per app anymore, which sucks, and doubly so because they haven't bothered to mention of this change to established functionality anywhere.